# Dump broken Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-9.6

I have database, it's work, but has some problems. I need to migrate database to new Version Postgres, so when I try to make dump with pg_dump or pg_dumpall I got somethink like this:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  unexpected chunk number 2 (expected 0) for toast value 78482 in pg_toast_2618
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT pg_catalog.pg_get_viewdef('78478'::pg_catalog.oid) AS viewdef
```

But, if I make dump only one separate table it works.
I want to make dump by piecemeal. I already got structure of all tables, script for create actual indexes. When I made pg_dumpall of other normal database, I saw in dump-file something like:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY schema_name.table_name ALTER COLUMN id_column SET DEFAULT nextval('sequence_name'::regclass);
```

I need write script which set sequence for each table, where I can to see matching between sequences and tables?
Someone has expirience in such migration? Which problems waits me later? There are special instruments for migration database postgres? Any diferent solutions?

Comment: You can use `pg_dump` to just dump the schema with `-s` so you get the whole thing with relations, sequences, indexes etc at once, if that works

Comment: I wrote upper it's not work! I used keys -s but there is unexpected chunk in system catalog